# How to stack topbar dropdown menu on top of navbar?

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

I have a navbar with a tiny topbar above it. This topbar has a dropdown button with a dropdown menu. How can I make this dropdown show on top of the navbar? I cannot change `position:fixed;` on the navbar or topbar because these two have been aligned.

Changing the `z-index:x;` property on either of those `<div>` items has no effect and making one elements `z-index:x!important;` does nothing either. What can I do?

```css
.topbar {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1!important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
.navbar {
    margin-top: 32px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3!important;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00);
    border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(55,175,75,1.00);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 2!important;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar" align="center">
  <p>Topbar content and buttons</p>
  <div class="dropdown" align="center">Dropdown content</div>
</div>
<div class="navbar" align="center">Navbar content and buttons</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

This problem is solved by placing the `<div class="topbar"></div>` and the `<div class="navbar"></div>` inside a `<div></div>` with property `position:fixed;` and deleting the fixed position in the topbar and navbar.